# Same code, same browser, different behavior for users

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of JS code which parses through a file, then associated the array with a key-value pair map, and then iterates it through it to find the proper city name with a .includes method. My problem is that the final field (where the function in question is called) works fine on my end for both Chrome and Firefox. It does not work for some reason for my group members.

This is the JS snippet that does the iterating:

Edit: this is how the file is being opened:

```
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "../data/myFile.txt", false);
```

---

```
for (var i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    myMap[allText[i]] = allText[i + 1];
  }
}

var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
for (var key in myMap) {
  if (myMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (myMap[key].toLowerCase().includes(city.toLowerCase())) {
      document.getElementById("city").value = myMap[key]
      document.getElementById("zipcode").value = key;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the html part that calls it:

```
<label for="myLabel">City: </label>
<input type="text" name="myLabel" id="myLabel" onblur="readTextFile()">
```

What exactly is the problem and how can I troubleshoot it as it makes no sense to me, coming from the world of Java and C++, where I have never faced such an issue before. If you are wondering why the JS might be kinda ugly, it is the result of a student with a teacher who thinks that showing W3Schools examples is equivalent to good teaching.

Comment: use chrome, and step thru the code, go to the sources tab (f12) and put a breakpoint on your problem line ?

Comment: well for me it won't matter as it works on my end. I guess they can try that.

Comment: why ask the question if it won't matter

Comment: Are your group members using the same browser/version? `String.includes` [is not universally supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Because maybe there is something in that that might be specific to a new version of JS that maybe they don't have? Maybe some insight can be gained, idk, stack is my teacher for this class as the professor is useless

Comment: could be as Rob M said you need to check versions

Comment: Is this being run locally or on a server, because it may be a user permissions issue if it is running locally.

Comment: Edit: doing ls -l on file is all rwx rwx rwx

Comment: You have to define "does not work". Tell the other folks to open devtools, and report to you what error is reported there. Or, instrument your code with something like `window.onerror`, and report the error to a server somewhere where you can view it.

Comment: did you check the server logs that myFile. txt is actually delivered to those users and not, say HTTP 403 error or no reqeuest arriving due to proxy settings...?

Comment: _It does not work for some reason for my group members_... then have them look at their JavaScript consoles.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript includes function may work erratically due to some browsers not supporting it. You need to be wise while choosing the javascript functions specially when mozilla may have some functions which are not supported on some browsers. W3schools also provides a list of Browser support for a function. Check the link below for that list for includes function:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Alternatively, you can use indexOf function like:

```
     myMap[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(city.toLowerCase()) >= 0
```

I have myself faced issues with includes function hence providing you a workaround. Happy programming.

Comment: will give it a shot.